# Is / l / in “whole” dark or clear?

Tags: phonetics, consonants

Is / l / in “whole” dark or clear?

I know that a clear ( or palatalised ) / l / is in a prevocalic position; nonetheless, I also know that the dark / l /  ( or velarised ) is usually at the end of words

Answer (score 1):

When the L precedes a vowel, it's often called a Light L. For example, love, light, lamp etc.

When the /l/ comes at the end of a word (after a vowel), it's often realised dark L ([velarised l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_lateral_approximants#Velarized_alveolar_lateral_approximant)).
Whether or not it's velarised depends on the accent.

Examples: Hell, bell, doll etc.

'Whole' is pronounced /həʊl/ ([həʊ̯ɫ]) i.e. the e is silent, so the /l/ is velarised in many accents.